# window7 X64 VS2015 ASP.NET ORA9I ORA-12154

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2015, windows-7

My Environment is 
1)Windows X64
2)Oracle 9i installed in c:\ora9i
3)IDE:VS2015

When I use ConsoleApplication There is no exception;

[image: ConsoleApplication]

When I Use Asp.net Web Fomr There is exception ORA-12154
[image]

Comment: Please read this then consider revising your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My code is very simple ,so i use picture.Is there any problem?

Comment: Please provide full error message in english

Comment: call t_conn.Open() throw OracleException ORA-12154

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle (i.e. `System.Data.OracleClient`) is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for ages, you should not use it.

It is available only for 32 bit. I assume your Console Application is compiled with Target = x86 but your ASP.net Web project is set to x64 or AnyCPU.

Use modern data provider from Oracle, you can download them from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)